# Dependent Care FSA Reimbrusement

Tags: united-states, fsa, eligible-expenses, job-change

I had FSA with past employer from Jan to Sept 2019 and then switched Job with new employer and started FSA amount with the rest of the limit. All my dependent care expenses were till Sept 2019 but when I submit past receipt new employer is asking that service should be after Sept 2019. Does that mean I will lose money?

Answer (score 1):

Each employer can reimburse expenses from the period of employment only. You would have needed to submit reimbursement for those expenses through September to the first employer.. usually the employee has a 90-day grace period in which to do that.

This is the sort of thing that makes FSA participation challenging - it is really necessary to stay totally up-to-date in order to not lose any funds.